# With Swift, is there a way to open URL and get the http error

Tags: swift, http-error, openurl

I'm doing

```
if !UIApplication.shared.openURL(url) {         
    print("Error")
}
```

The issue is that I've the message error in the console and I'm seeking how to know what specific HTTP error is thrown.

Comment: Try to do a request on it with `URLSession` instead of opening it in `Safari.app`?

Comment: `UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)` check your can be opened or your url is valid or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your responses by doing something like this.

```
let URL = URL(string: "www.google.com")
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!) { _, response, _ in 
     if let status = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
          print(status.statusCode)
     }
}

task.resume()
```

*Apologies for any syntax issues. No XCode available at the moment.*